# Running a C++ executable with "< inputfile" that uses system to run a C executable that reads from the inputfile

Tags: c++, c

I wrote a program called "check" in C code that determines if an input file is in the correct format. I can give the file name as a command-line argument or use stdin. It works exactly as intended.

I wrote another program called "winnable" in C++ code that is just printing out the contents of the file to "cout" using "getline(cin, string)" in a while loop. "winnable" also takes a file name argument or stdin. "winnable" calls check (I am using system()) to verify the file is correct before printing the file contents.

The problem: While using the input file name as a command-line argument works as expected, typing in "./winnable < inputfile" I only get the output from "check" and nothing from "winnable".

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: We can't know what your code might be doing wrong if you don't show it to us.

Comment: `stdin` is a read once stream. Once the first programs consumes the input it can't be read by the next program unless you explicitly handle that. This is different to a file where both programs can independantly open/read/close the file.

Comment: Okay, I put "rewind(input)" in my check file and then my C++ program is working correctly again.

Comment: This cannot work with stdin.